# Problem Importing JSON data in CosmosDB from Azure Data Factory Copy

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

My Azure data Factory Pipeline has a COPY operation to **COPY data from CSV to CosmosDB**.
CSV file has 3 columns to import in CosmosDB.

CosmosDB Collection will receive:

```
Column1 in Partition Key
Column2 in Id
Column3 whole JSON Value
```

when I run COPY it copies the data in String format in CosmosDB for all 3 columns. Because **there is no JSON or Map type available** while we specify ColumnType.

[image]

What should I do to import JSON in value field, instead of String or TEXT. Below is the sample I am getting in CosmosDB:
[image]

Comment: any other replies..? or If we can PUSH JSON Data directly from Notebook to CosmosDB?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong I am not allowed to use Azure Functions yet in our PROD.

Comment: @AnilKapoor did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, no such features could help you convert string data to object format in adf cosmos db configuration.

So, as workaround, I suggest you using [Azure Function Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) to process every document when they imported into database. Please refer to my function code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

namespace TestADF
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "db",
            collectionName: "item",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "documentdbstring",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, TraceWriter log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.Verbose("Start.........");
                String endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
                String authorizationKey = "key";
                String databaseId = "db";
                String collectionId = "item";

                DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);

                for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
                {
                    Document doc = input[i];
                    if ((doc.GetPropertyValue<String>("Value") == null) || (!doc.GetPropertyValue<String>("Value")))
                    {                       
                        String V= doc.GetPropertyValue<String>("Value");
                        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(V);

                        doc.SetPropertyValue("Value", obj );

                        client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, doc.Id), doc);

                        log.Verbose("Update document Id " + doc.Id);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```